# form not flagging errors on eachstep & running php code when submitted

Tags: jquery, idealforms

when all fields are correctit gives msg all good but doesn't run thephp code associated with isset also how do i get it to flag errors when next btn is clicked before displaying the next step/form

```
 <div class="idealsteps-container">
<nav class="idealsteps-nav"></nav>
<form class="idealforms" novalidate autocomplete="off" action="/" method="post">

<div class="idealsteps-wrap"> 

<!-- Step 1 -->

<section class="idealsteps-step">
<div class="field">
<label class="main">Book Name:</label>
<input name="bookname" type="text" >
<span class="error"></span> </div>

<div class="field buttons">
<label class="main">&nbsp;</label>
<button type="button" class="next">Next &raquo;</button>
</div>
</section>

<!-- Step 2-->

<section class="idealsteps-step">
<div class="field">
<label class="main">code:</label>
<input name="code" type="text">
<span class="error"></span> </div>

<div class="field buttons">
<label class="main">&nbsp;</label>
<button type="button" class="prev">&laquo; Prev</button>
<button type="submit" id="btn" name="btn" class="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
</section>
</div>
<span id="invalid"></span>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['btn']))
{
echo "submitted";
}
?>
<script>
$('form.idealforms').idealforms({

silentLoad: false,

rules: {
'bookname': 'required bookname'
},

onSubmit: function(invalid, e) {
e.preventDefault();
$('#invalid')
.show()
.toggleClass('valid', ! invalid)
.text(invalid ? (invalid +' invalid fields') : 'All good!');

}
});
</script>
```

currently it flags errors only when the submit btn in step2 is clicked,how do i get it to show errors of tht step before proceeding to next step also to run the php code when final submit btn is clicked

Comment: It's not </?php,  it's <?php

Comment: there's no closing tag for form either

Comment: added it..missed it when copy pasting

Comment: its still not working after adding...anyone plz?